# How to read data ( scan text ) from CameraImage in Flutter (Android )

Tags: android, flutter, image, camera, google-mlkit

I want to scan text with live camera . And for that I'm using google_ml_kit package for scanning. In ios platform everything is okay. But I cannot read data from CameraImage in android.
And also I got this message :

'A camera has started streaming images., startImageStream was called while a camera was streaming images.'

My code is :

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    controller = CameraController(widget.cameras[0], ResolutionPreset.medium,
        enableAudio: false);

    controller.initialize().then((_) {
      if (!mounted) {
        return;
      }

      setState(() {});
      _timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 3), (currentTimer) async {
        await controller.startImageStream((CameraImage availableImage) async {
          _scanText(availableImage);
        });
      });
    });
  }

  void _scanText(CameraImage availableImage) async {
    try {
      if (_isScanBusy) return;
      
        _isScanBusy = true;
      

      final WriteBuffer allBytes = WriteBuffer();
      for (Plane plane in availableImage.planes) {
        allBytes.putUint8List(plane.bytes);
      }
      final bytes = allBytes.done().buffer.asUint8List();

      final Size imageSize = Size(
          availableImage.width.toDouble(), availableImage.height.toDouble());

      final InputImageRotation imageRotation =
          InputImageRotationMethods.fromRawValue(
                  widget.cameras[0].sensorOrientation) ??
              InputImageRotation.Rotation_0deg;

      final InputImageFormat inputImageFormat =
          InputImageFormatMethods.fromRawValue(availableImage.format.raw) ??
              InputImageFormat.YUV420;

      final planeData = availableImage.planes.map(
        (Plane plane) {
          return InputImagePlaneMetadata(
            bytesPerRow: plane.bytesPerRow,
            height: plane.height,
            width: plane.width,
          );
        },
      ).toList();

      final inputImageData = InputImageData(
        size: imageSize,
        imageRotation: imageRotation,
        inputImageFormat: inputImageFormat,
        planeData: planeData,
      );

      final inputImage =
          InputImage.fromBytes(bytes: bytes, inputImageData: inputImageData);

      final textDetector = GoogleMlKit.vision.textDetector();
      final RecognisedText recognisedText =
          await textDetector.processImage(inputImage);
      //do something

        
      }
      _isScanBusy = false;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Comment: ML Kit team doesn't own the flutter plugin so I'd suggest you to look for help from this community. https://github.com/bharat-biradar/Google-Ml-Kit-plugin

Comment: this is google ml kit plugin